# Threads not running in parallel for a system command

Tags: python, macos, python-multithreading

This is my script

```
import threading
import os

class Say(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        super(Say, self).__init__()
        self.cmd = cmd
    def run(self):
        os.system(self.cmd)

t1 = Say("afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff")
t2 = Say("afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff")
t1.start()
print("a")
t2.start()
print("b")
```

It appears that both starts are executed immediately. However, the sounds are not played in parallel but one after the other.

When running the following shell script

```
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff &
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff &
```

both sounds play at the same time. What makes Python run the commands sequentially instead of parallel?

I'm using Big Sur with with the standard Python (2.7).

Comment: Is there a difference between running `afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff` and  `afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff &` (I mean the `&` at the end)?

Comment: Does the same problem happen with something like `t1 = Say("echo start 1; sleep 1; echo end 1"); t2 = Say("echo start 2; sleep 1; echo end 2")`? Because I can't reproduce with that.

Comment: @user202729 Yes, forgot to copy...

Comment: @JakubSzlaur Well, those are different sounds. The & at the end makes it send to the background.

Comment: @user202729 What should I see in the code you asked for? The output goes to nirwana. I want to hear the sounds at the same time (overlayed).

Comment: The expected behavior is for the code to terminate after one second...

Comment: Because if the problem doesn't happen with `sleep`, it could be a `afplay`-specific issue.

Comment: @user202729 As written, the Python code goes through in a rush, but the sounds are heard like Tink, Ping. The shell script calls the same executable and I hear TPink (both sounds one over the other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).  In particular I'm guessing that when `os.system` is called in `t1`, the GIL locks and doesn't unlock until the command returns, preventing `t2` from running any python code.

If I replace

```
os.system(self.cmd)
```

with

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', self.cmd])
```

then the problem goes away.

For that matter, since you are spawning separate processes at any event and doing nothing with their output, there is no point in creating all these threads; you can get the same effect by replacing your entire code sample with

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Tink.aiff"])
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff"])
```

Comment: You hit the nail. Actually I don't care about threads in this case. All I wanted was parallel execution. I have never heard about GIL but now it's good to know that there is something like that!

Comment: Still, I can't reproduce using `sleep` (Python 3.9.1 / 2.7.18) Either there's something wrong with this answer, or it's macOS-specific, or they fixed the issue in some later version.

Comment: @user202729: I can reproduce using `sleep` on recent Ubuntu running on x86.  I'm using python 3.8.5; I guess it's not impossible they fixed it in 3.9.

Comment: I still get `start 1; start 2; end 1; end 2` on TIO (https://tio.run/##bVDLasMwELzrKxafJAgCO7eGfkVyN6q9qQW2JLTrgr/eWTmxW0r2NMyLkdLCQwzndfVTipmBh4yu9@FbvYhIO6KFlErZB9YC7Q9m8jEYpbrREcHVLfpI29uGzIcCuR7v0LY@eG5bTTjeT9BNu1iO5oRZS8MJimzs4Ta/HhGsxOCzhI/ePIet8k9bJCsDGSe9Z2Qk1xIsGyvshgjETp5UX4BGxFTARmPooa7MBbh5Y2/e2ZvKSLndHDL3@UGVK2zzn/0Sdl0f) (Python 3.7.4).